# Import a range of cells from excel sheet into a datatable

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, datatable

I have a data report in Excel which has got some 'header information text' in top 20 rows and then from 22nd row onward all the data stuff starts. i.e. 22nd row has all the column header names (10 columns) and then 23rd onward is the data.

I basically want to extract just the data part (i.e. 22nd row onward) from the report and import into a datatable or 'oracledatareader'.

Any help would be really appreciated.

I am using visual studio 2012.

Comment: Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask]

Comment: Do I need to re-post my question or is it ok for now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Excel library for C#](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library) and import the range you need or the entire sheet data into a DataSet.

If you will import only the range of cell, you should know where the range ends.

If you don't know, you have to import the entire sheet and delete the first 21 rows from the DataTable.

Check some samples of code at this link:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/import-excel-to-dataset.html